# pulling specific data from XML from inside 3rd party application

Tags: vbscript

Another script that is used as a token to extract information from a 3rd party application,  the application does other things in the background that I don't specifically know about.

This code does work inside the parent application and produces the expected output.

Is there a nicer way to write this code?

```vb
Public Function GetParameterXml()
    GetParameterXml = _
        "<Parameters>" &_
        "<Parameter Value='Age' Code='A' Description='Age' Type='Combo' Tooltip='Would you like the newest or oldest Reason?'>" &_
        "    <Options>" &_
        "   <Option Code='O' Description='Oldest' Value='OLD' />" &_
        "   <Option Code='N' Description='Newest' Value='NEW' />" &_
        "    </Options>" &_
        "</Parameter>" &_
        "</Parameters>"
End Function

'Parameter Variables
Dim Age : Set Age = Parameters.Item( Bookmark , "Age" )

' PlaceHolder Variables
Dim oNodes
Dim oNode

Set oNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent")

'''stop here and look around
stop

If (Age.Value = "OLD") Then
    For Each iNode in oNodes(0).childNodes
        If iNode.nodeName = "Service" Then
            For Each jNode in iNode.childNodes
                If jNode.nodeName = "Comment" Then
                    ReturnData = ReturnData & jNode.text & MD & ""
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next       
    If Len(ReturnData) > 0 Then
        ReturnData = Left(ReturnData, Len(ReturnData) - Len(MD))
    Else
        ReturnData = ""
    End if
ElseIf (Age.Value = "NEW") Then
    For Each iNode in oNodes(oNodes.length - 1).childNodes
        If iNode.nodeName = "Service" Then
            For Each jNode in iNode.childNodes
                If jNode.nodeName = "Comment" Then
                    ReturnData = ReturnData & jNode.text & MD & ""
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    If Len(ReturnData) > 0 Then
        ReturnData = Left(ReturnData, Len(ReturnData) - Len(MD))
    Else
        ReturnData = ""
    End If  
Else
    ReturnData = " Hit the Else Statement "
End If
```

Comment: What's `MD`? Is it declared anywhere?

Comment: @retailcoder MD is a Delimiter used by the application for special formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I was able to come up with, thanks to @RetailCoder and some help on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617236/unknown-method-in-xpath-run-by-vbscript) Dealing with the `last()` function/method not working  I was able to add `xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"` to make it work for me.  so here is how I simplified the whole process.

- I replaced my `If...For...If...For` loops with a single switch statement and some XPath statements to grab the correct nodes
- I don't have to worry about if the `Comment` node exists or not, if `ReturnData` is empty it is taken care of by the last If statement.
- Removed the `& ""` like @retailcoder said

  > I left out the `& ""` part, because that's concatenating an empty string, which does strictly nothing but add confusing clutter to your code.
- There isn't anywhere to use the Joined Declaration & Assignment, the `CommentNodes` variable is set differently based on the Switch statement and Declaring it in both would be redundant.
- I didn't add a `Case Else` the way this script functions it is not necessary to follow this path should they input a bad parameter, the application of this script is hard to describe.  it is one of many tokens in a word document.
- one last thing, I only declared variables that I used in the rest of the script, the original had `oNode` and it was never used.
- I also didn't use any `Magic` iterator numbers like `iNode` or `jNode` even though I thought that was rather clever.

---

```
Public Function GetParameterXml()
    GetParameterXml = _
    "<Parameters>" &_
    "<Parameter Value='Age' Code='A' Description='Age' Type='Combo' Tooltip='Would you like the newest or oldest Reason?'>" &_
    "    <Options>" &_
    "   <Option Code='O' Description='Oldest' Value='OLD' />" &_
    "   <Option Code='N' Description='Newest' Value='NEW' />" &_
    "    </Options>" &_
    "</Parameter>" &_
    "</Parameters>"
End Function

'Parameter Variables
Dim Age : Set Age = Parameters.Item( Bookmark , "Age" )

' PlaceHolder Variables
Dim CommentNodes

''' stop here and look around
stop

xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

Select Case Age.Value
    Case "OLD":
        Set CommentNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent[1]/Service/Comment")
    Case "NEW":
        Set CommentNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent[position() = last()]/Service/Comment")
End Select

For Each CommentNode In CommentNodes
    ReturnData = ReturnData & CommentNode.Text & MD
Next

If Len(ReturnData) > 0 Then
    ReturnData = Left(ReturnData, Len(ReturnData) - Len(MD))
Else
    ReturnData = vbNullString 
End If
```

Obviously I am going to remove the breakpoint when I put this into production. but I think this really cleaned up the code.

Answer (score 3):

#### Joined declaration & assignment

This isn't necessarily a *bad* use of the `:` instruction separator, but it did surprise me. Actually, I'd even give you a star on that one:

> ```
> Dim Age : Set Age = Parameters.Item( Bookmark , "Age" )
> ```

Pretty much *any other use I can think of* of the `:` instruction separator is hindering readability. Here I find it's a clever way of joining declaration with assignment.

However this:

> ```
> Dim oNodes
> Dim oNode
>
> Set oNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent")
> ```

Should then be written like this:

```
Dim xPath : xPath = "Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/ServiceEvent"
Dim ServiceEventNodes : Set ServiceEventNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes(xPath)
```

I'm not going to mention I'm allergic to things like an "o" prefix to object variables' names (oops just did), but I think you'll agree with me that `ServiceEventNodes` is a much more descriptive name than `oNodes` can ever dream to be.

I've skipped `oNode` here because.. I'll get there in a moment.

---

> ```
> '''stop here and look around
> ```

I'll skip the `Stop` keyword and hope this isn't production code. This isn't a necessary comment, but it's well-placed - stop right here and look below, you've got `If...For...If...For...If` blocks nicely (!) nested here. I'd say *stop here and fill up your lungs with that horrible smell*, you've got two blocks of code that are rigorously identical, *except* for one tiny little thing; how about first deciding what the child nodes are, *and then* iterate them, regardless of `Age.Value`?

```
Dim ChildNodes
Select Case Age.Value
    Case "OLD":
        Set ChildNodes = ServiceEventNodes(0).childNodes
    Case "NEW":
        Set ChildNodes = ServiceEventNodes(ServiceEventNodes.length - 1).childNodes
    Case Else:
        Err.Raise 5 'invalid procedure call or argument
End Select
```

Notice this is **not** allowing the code to run any further if there's an invalid input. Returning `" Hit the Else Statement "` **is a dangerous thing to do**, because it's a valid value that your function will return just as if everything went normal, and I don't know what that's used for, but I'm sure `" Hit the Else Statement "` doesn't quite belong in production data.

That's why I'd rather throw an error and blow up than return a string that's actually an error message.

---

That being settled, I believe both loops could be completely eliminated with a little XPath (untested; I *think* this would do it):

```
Dim CommentNodes : Set CommentNodes = ChildNodes.SelectNodes("Service/Comment")
```

Now that you've got the nodes you're after, you can iterate them:

```
Dim CommentNode
For Each CommentNode In CommentNodes
    ReturnData = ReturnData & CommentNode.Text & MD
Next
```

I left out the `& ""` part, because that's concatenating an empty string, which does strictly nothing but add confusing clutter to your code.

The last part:

> ```
> If Len(ReturnData) > 0 Then
>     ReturnData = Left(ReturnData, Len(ReturnData) - Len(MD))
> Else
>     ReturnData = ""
> End If
> ```

Looks like it's working around the fact that you haven't properly declared and initialized `ReturnData` in the first place. If you put `Dim ReturnData : ReturnData = vbNullString` somewhere before the loop, then you don't need to assign it to an empty string if the loop resulted in a no-op.

Comment: I like this. the reason for the weird if else stuff going on is... the structure of the XML that is being read in.  there are multiple ServiceEvent Nodes with 1+ Service node where each one can have a comment, but sometimes they don't, if they do, return the text, even if there is more than one.

Comment: I was having a heck of a time trying to get the xPath to play nice with the VBScript on `Service/Comment` the way I wanted the Data. I am sure there hasn't been any testing by the Business Analysts yet, so I should be able to put this stuff into play,  I will learn me to code VBScript sooner or later.

Comment: sorry for all the comments but I think it is relevant to the answer,  this is not Production Code. and the only way to know about an exception is to have something returned via `ReturnData`.  I work for the judicial system so this application creates forms (that are editable) and fills in the data.  one line that I didn't include was the first line, `on error resume next`

Comment: `ReturnData` is a Variable that is created and used by the application. I don't think that I should mess with that.  Code for this is like coding with my nose because I have my hands tied behind my back.

Comment: what if the `Comment` node Doesn't exist for that specific `Service` Node? I think that might be a dumb question.  I am just trying to make sure I haven't changed the functionality of what I was doing

Comment: @Malachi you make an XPath that selects all comment nodes, regardless of which "service" node they're under - that's the trick :)

Comment: but then it will grab comments from the other `ServiceEventNodes` right?  and what if no Comment nodes exist?

Comment: Hmm right. I'll edit.

Comment: ok when I try running this, on `Set CommentNodes = ChildNodes.SelectNodes("Service/Comment")` it gives me a runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'SelectNodes'  that is the main reason why I went with the clunky For each loops and if statements.

Comment: @Malachi Right. `ChildNodes` is a `IXMLDOMNodeList`, you need to iterate it once. Sorry :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11958/discussion-between-malachi-and-retailcoder)